# Export nodes from Drupal 4?

Tags: upgrading

I am looking into updating a Drupal 4 site. The Node Export module does not seem to have a release suitable for Drupal 4. Can anyone recommend an alternative module or procedure?

The site is running Drupal 4.6.3.

Answer (score 4):

I'm assuming you're on a shared server. Here are some options.

Option 1 - Downgrade PHP.
Although it might not be the safest choice, as both the PHP and Drupal is probably no longer supported, you can do the following.

- Some hosts allow to specify a different PHP version in php.ini.
- Rent a cheap VPS, which will allow you to set the PHP version.
- Some shared hosts specialize with older PHP versions, make a switch.

Option 2 - Use backup and migrate modules.
There are a number of backup and migrate drupal modules which will make the migrating process easier. This would be a safer choice, but the downside, is that you'll loose your theme and you might have to upgrade to ->5, ->6 and only then to ->7. Here are a few modules to look at

- [Backup and Migrate](http://drupal.org/project/backup_migrate)
- [Backup](http://drupal.org/project/backup)

Option 3 - Start from scratch, import in bulk.
It's both safe and probably the best choice. Set up a new site and a theme. Export the data from the old site, using feeds, or other Drupal modules and import it into the new site using modules like [Migrate](http://drupal.org/project/migrate).

I would advise to upgrade to D7, since the support for D6, not alone D5, will be dropped soon.

Answer (score 2):

I don't go back as far as 4, but if it's just content you're after, I think you can disable all the modules, then do an upgrade to 5. Once that's working, do an upgrade to 6, then to 7. I think if you're not worried about modules, the upgrades work just fine, or at least this was my experience going from 5 to 6. Unfortunately, I'm a bit ignorant of going 4 to 5.

Comment: Hi Jonathan. The upgrade would be to Drupal 7. I'll look into the approach you suggested - thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Even i faced same problem. After trying few export modules, decided to write my own php code to move content from Drupal 4 to Drupal 7. Here i am sharing the link, someone may get some help out of this: http://goo.gl/GPmG9F

> Drupal having a huge support with version 6 > but no support with 4.X and limited support to 5.x.
>   Initially I install few module to import node/content with CSV/XML, but they are not working as expected. I need to import content first which include mainly title, description images (more than one) and attachments (more than 1) for each content. I checked feed, taxanomy csv import, migrate and couple of more but they are able to upload content but not images and attachments. So I thought of writing our own script which will read each node from Drupal 4.x and insert directly into Drupal 7.x database.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.